# Having issue on Loading Meta Data From CSV to CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, theme-development, csv

I have a custom post type which has one Title, and two meta box  custom fields as

```
$price = isset( $we_productMetas['price_box'] ) ? esc_attr( $we_productMetas['price_box'][0] ) : '';
$color = isset( $we_productMetas['color_box'] ) ? esc_attr( $we_productMetas['color_box'][0] ) : '';
```

and I have some data in a CSV file in this format

```
title,price,color
Item1,50,red
Item2,20,green
Item3,60,red
Item4,10,blue
```

Using following code I am able to load the `title` of the post properly and publish the CSV but I am missing the `price` and `color` metadada

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know what I am doing wrong at

```
      $post["id"] = wp_insert_post( array(
                "post_title" => $post["title"],
                "post_type" => $cpt["custom-post-type"],
                "custom-field-1" =>$cpt["custom-field-1"],
                "custom-field-2" =>$cpt["custom-field-2"],
                "post_status" => "publish"
            ));
```

Here is the entire code

```
add_action( "admin_notices", function() {
    echo "<div class='updated'>";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "To insert the posts into the database, click the button to the right.";
    echo "<a class='button button-primary' style='margin:0.25em 1em' href='{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}&insert_cpt_posts'>Insert Posts</a>";
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
});

add_action( "admin_init", function() {
    global $wpdb;
if ( ! isset( $_GET["insert_cpt_posts"] ) ) {
    return;
}

$cpt = array(
    "custom-field-1" => "price_box",
    "custom-field-2" => "color_box",
    "custom-post-type" => "women_eyeglasses"
);

$posts = function() {
    $data = array();
    $errors = array();

    // Get array of CSV files
    $files = glob( __DIR__ . "/*.csv" );
    foreach ( $files as $file ) {
        if ( is_readable( $file ) && $_file = fopen( $file, "r" ) ) {
            $post = array();
            $header = fgetcsv( $_file );
            while ( $row = fgetcsv( $_file ) ) {
                foreach ( $header as $i => $key ) {
                    $post[$key] = $row[$i];
                }
                $data[] = $post;
            }
            fclose( $_file );

        } else {
            $errors[] = "File '$file' could not be opened. Check the file's permissions to make sure it's readable by your server.";
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $errors ) ) {

    }

    return $data;
};

$post_exists = function( $title ) use ( $wpdb, $cpt ) {
$posts = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = '{$cpt["custom-post-type"]}'" );
      return in_array( $title, $posts );
    };

    foreach ( $posts() as $post ) {
            if ( $post_exists( $post["title"] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            // Insert the post into the database
            $post["id"] = wp_insert_post( array(
                "post_title" => $post["title"],
                "post_type" => $cpt["custom-post-type"],
                "custom-field-1" =>$cpt["custom-field-1"],
                "custom-field-2" =>$cpt["custom-field-2"],
                "post_status" => "publish"
            ));
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your metas need to be passed to `wp_insert_post()` as an array like so:

```
// Insert the post into the database
$post["id"] = wp_insert_post( array(
    "post_title" => $post["title"],
    "post_type" => $cpt["custom-post-type"],
    "meta_input" => array(
        "custom-field-1" =>$cpt["custom-field-1"],
        "custom-field-2" =>$cpt["custom-field-2"],
    )
    "post_status" => "publish"
));
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#parameters

Comment: Thanks a lots Lewis, I updated the code based on your help but I was not getting anything in metas. So I changed the `"custom-field-1" =>$cpt["custom-field-1"],` to  `"price_box" =>$cpt["custom-field-1"],` and the ` "custom-field-2" =>$cpt["custom-field-2"],` to `"colors\_box" =>$cpt["custom-field-2"],`  now this is storing strings of `price_box` and `colors_box` from the `$cpt []` but looks like is not reading the data from the CSV